# Fastlane gym fails after adding cocoapods dependency

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, fastlane-gym

Although I installed the gem "cocoapods" and did the "pod install" command in the correct directory (platforms/ios in my case, because we are building an IONIC app), my build which is using `fastlane gym` fails with this message:

```
library not found for -lPods-Appname
```

[this link helped me solve this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1552)

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that in my Fastfile I had gym configured to use the 
`project` parameter. I changed this -> now I use the `workspace` parameter instead for gym and it works.

Just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement anha1979's answer:

Not only do you have to change `project` to `workspace`, don't forget to change `appname.xcodeproj` to `appname.xcworkspace` too!